# Writing 'anonymous' subclasses for unit testing?

Tags: python, class, unit-testing

I currently have a Python `unittest` test case like the following:

```
from unittest import TestCase as UTestCase

import inspect 

class BaseParentTaskTest(UTestCase):

    def test_case_one(self):
        class A(BaseParentTask):
            def run(self, a, b):
                pass

        instance = A()

        print inspect.getargspec(instance.run).args

        instance._validate()

        if instance.valid:
            self.fail("Failed to invalidate based on wrong argument count.")

    def test_case_two(self):
        class A(BaseParentTask):
            def run(self, a, b, c, d):
                pass

        instance = A()

        print inspect.getargspec(instance.run).args

        if instance.valid:
            self.fail("Failed to invalidate based on wrong argument kw names.")
```

It seems that from my testing, after running `test_case_one`, the `A` class is kept in memory and not overwritten by `A` in `test_case_two` when that runs. This causes `test_case_two` to fail.

This can be seen from the logs. In `test_case_one`, the expected output is `(self, a, b)`, and it is:

```
(self, a, b)
```

In `test_case_two`, the expected output is `(self, a, b, c, d)`:

```
(self, a, b)
```

However, it's clearly not.

Why is the `A` class not obliterated as soon as the instance method exits? How can I fix this to make my tests pass?

Comment: The `A` class _is_ obliterated - something else is happening

Comment: Any ideas on how to check that?

Comment: What does `BaseParentTask` look like?

Comment: Try printing `id(A)` and `id(type(instance))` in both places.

Comment: `A = type('A', (BaseParentTask,), {'run': (lambda self, a, b, c:None)})`

Comment: Celery was to blame here, as it was doing some creepy stuff internally to store only one type of `Task` with the name of `A`. Making the tasks abstract solved the problem, weirdly enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Evidently, Celery is to blame here, as it's doing some weird stuff behind the scenes to make this happen.

By defining the `abstract` class variable on each of the subclasses, the problem goes away:

```
class A(BaseParentTask):
    abstract = True
    def run(self, a, b, c, d):
        pass
```

My understanding was that Celery wouldn't do anything with the class unless it was registered with the `@celery.task` annotation, but it seems that it internally still registers the class without any explicit request to do so.